# Extended Result of Div. Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm currently studying the [division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm) and was wondering how one could show this algorithm holds when $a \leq0$. Here is the entire question:

> Show that if $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a \leq 0$ and $b \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\exists!$ $q,r\in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $a = q \cdot b + r$, where $0 \leq r < b.$

Well, I want to show that there does exist an $r$ and a $q$, then show that they are unique. I already know the proof when $a>0$ (already discussed with my fellow peers), but I wouldn't imagine it to be much more different by having $a \leq0$. I also know that the [Well-ordering Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle) will have to come into play somehow, but how do I incorporate that into showing this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a=0$, then $a=0= 0\cdot b +0$ and the result is established.

Let $a < 0$. Assuming that the result holds for positive integers, there are unique integers $q$ and $r$ such that $|a| = qb + r$. Thus,
$$ a =-|a| = -(qb + r) = (-q)b - r .$$ 
If $r=0$, then the result is established; otherwise, notice that 
$$ a =-(q+1)b +(b-r).$$ 
Since  $0 < r < b$, it follows that $0< b-r < b$ and the result holds for this case as well.

The uniqueness argument is not case-dependent, so the result is established.

Comment: For instance, $-3=-|-3|$.

Comment: Many apologies, but please disregard my earlier comment since I glanced over the condition $a<0$. Other than that, this proof should suffice. I would have never thought of using absolute values.